# How do I implement itertools.permutations in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to find a way to generate a tensor of permutations using tensorflow.

Basically, I'd like to have a function like the following:

```py
out = tf_permutations(tf.range(3))
```

Where the output would be:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(6, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: `tf.transpose(a, perm=None, conjugate=False, name='transpose')`, Permutes the dimensions according to the value of perm. The returned tensor's dimension i will correspond to the input dimension perm[i]. For more details look [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose). Thanks!

Comment: I'm not looking to permute dimensions. I was hoping to produce a series of permutations just like the itertools function.